# Adding Parameter to File Path in ExpressJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I am attempting to upload particular photos in reference to a client's folder in my public/assets directory. The file path should be public/assets/:id. However, from my code, when it is ran the file path always is returned as public/assets/undefined. Does anyone have suggestions as to how to fix this ? Here is the code in express.

```
app.param('id', function (req, res, next, id) {
 console.log(req.params.id);
  next();
  });
app.post('/file-upload', function(req, res) {
  // get the temporary location of the file
 var tmp_path = req.files.thumbnail.path;
  // set where the file should actually exists - in this case it is in the "images" directory
 var target_path = './public/assets/'+req.params.id;
  // move the file from the temporary location to the intended location
 fs.rename(tmp_path, target_path, function(err) {
    if (err) throw err;
    // delete the temporary file, so that the explicitly set temporary upload dir does not get filled with unwanted files
    fs.unlink(tmp_path, function() {
        if (err) throw err;
        res.send('File uploaded to: ' + target_path + ' - ' + req.files.thumbnail.size + ' bytes');
     });
  });
});
```

Comment: There are no params in the path `/file-upload`, so `req.params.id` will indeed be undefined.

You can achieve what you want by POSTing the `id` in a hidden field or sending it in a cookie.

Answer (score 2):

In routing you are not passing your parameter , please check and change your route logic like this

```
app.post('/file-upload/:id', function(req, res) {

 var target_path = './public/assets/'+req.params.id; //or use req.param('id')

  ................

});
```

Post link pass your second segment is your id 
example : http://localhost:port/file-upload/123

If you facing problem please use Passing variables as query string using '?' operator

```
  app.post('/file-upload', function(req, res) {

     var target_path = './public/assets/'+req.query.id; 

      ................

    });
```

Post link your like this
example : http://localhost:port/file-upload?id=123

Answer (score 0):

You can use `:id` in the first argument of `.post` like:

```
app.post('/file-upload/:id', function(req, res) {
```

and then retrieve like you are doing in the code with `req.params.id`.

In the HTML you should change the `action` path according to the `id` you want to pass.

Comment: When I put `<form method="post" action="/file-upload/{{client.id}}">` I get an error that says [$interpolate:noconcat]